# How start two windows/frames of emacs with emacsclient?

Tags: emacs, daemon, emacsclient

I would like to create multiple frames/windows of emacs. Emacs is started by `emacs --daemon` and I am invoking emacs by `emacsclient`.

I specify I want a other window/frame by `-c` option : `emacsclient -c`.

But even with `-c` option, I can't start another frame/window. Calling two times `emacsclient -c` produces one window/frame (first invocation) and another window/frame which open very briefly and shutdown straight (graphically speaking, I only see a flash).

How do I start two (or more) different frames/windows of emacsclient graphically separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix by removing `'(default ((t (:background "black" :foreground "white"))))` from .emacs.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/139436/how-to-fix-emacs-client-error-arithmetic-error) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not need to be automated for you, you could just do `C-x 5 2` to create a new frame. `C-x 5 0` will remove the frame.

**NOTE**

A frame in emacs is the entire graphical object.

A window in emacs is the separate sections of a frame. Including the mode lines.

A buffer in emacs is where you do the actual text editing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an error when typing `C-x 5 2` : `x-create-frame-with-faces: Arithmetic error`. Maybe this is why `emacsclient -c` does not work.

Comment: quite possibly. I have never seen this error myself. What X system do you have installed?

Comment: Debian unstable. Emacs 23.4.1.

Comment: I don't want to be mean or anything, but you are in a graphical system, and not just on a command line, right?

Comment: yes (I'm using xfce) but I found [a question](http://superuser.com/questions/139436/how-to-fix-emacs-client-error-arithmetic-error) which could answer to my problem. I'm looking into this and keep you updated.